# How to DrawImage on OSX with CGContext

Tags: macos, cgcontext, nsimage

I have a CGContext and I tried to draw an image on it.
I have a NSImage * load that i used on other method .

```
NSImage *check = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"check.icns"];
CGContextDrawImage(arg2, CGRectMake(0, 0, 145, 15), check);
```

But CGContext want a CGImage * how can I used my NSImage * ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turning an NSImage* into a CGImageRef?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548059/turning-an-nsimage-into-a-cgimageref)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider just opening it as a `CGImage` in this case, if that is all you will need it for. If an `NSImage` *is* what you need, then see `-[NSImage CGImageForProposedRect:context:hints:]`. This method may not require a copy, and it can produce a `CGImage` representation ideal for drawing into the destination context.

If needed, you can create a `NSGraphicsContext` from a `CGContext` using `+[NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:flipped:]`.