# ImageIO Error When Creating ICNS File

Tags: macos, cocoa, icons, icns

This code (`source` is an `NSMutableArray` with `NSImage` objects:

> ```
> NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:aPath];
> CGImageDestinationRef dr = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)fileURL,
>                                                            kUTTypeAppleICNS,
>                                                            1,
>                                                            NULL);
>
> for (NSImage *img in source) {
>
>     NSLog(@"%@",img);
>     CGImageRef i1 = [img CGImageForProposedRect:NULL context:nil hints:nil];
>     CGImageDestinationAddImage(dr, i1, NULL);
>
> }
>
> CGImageDestinationFinalize(dr);
> CFRelease(dr);
> ```

Resulted in the following output :

> 2012-12-26 13:48:57.682 Eicon[1131:1b0f] |NSImage 0x1025233b0 Size={11.52, 11.52} Reps=(
>       "NSBitmapImageRep 0x10421fc30 Size={11.52, 11.52} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=1024x1024 Alpha=NO Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x104221170"
>
> (...) <- here the other NSImage instances are logged.
>
> **ImageIO: |ERROR|  CGImageDestinationFinalize image destination does not have enough images**

Any ideas why it ends with the error at the end? (BTW, I thought of using IconFamily instead but a lot of the methods it uses are deprecated).

EDIT : Maybe it'd be more important to mention the code I use to generate the images, I wouldn't be surprised if that code has problems (I'm a noob) :

```
// Get images
[source removeAllObjects];
NSSize sizes[10];
sizes[0] = NSMakeSize(1024,1024);
sizes[1] = NSMakeSize(512,512);
sizes[2] = NSMakeSize(512,512);
sizes[3] = NSMakeSize(256,256);
sizes[4] = NSMakeSize(256,256);
sizes[5] = NSMakeSize(128,128);
sizes[6] = NSMakeSize(64,64);
sizes[7] = NSMakeSize(32,32);
sizes[8] = NSMakeSize(32,32);
sizes[9] = NSMakeSize(16,16);
for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Size%i",i+1]]) {
        NSBitmapImageRep *srcimg = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:aFile]];
        [srcimg setPixelsHigh:sizes[i].height];
        [srcimg setPixelsWide:sizes[i].width];
        NSImage *newimg = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSZeroSize];
        [newimg addRepresentation:srcimg];
        if (![newimg isValid]) {
            [delegate error:@"Invalid file."];
        }
        else [source addObject:newimg];
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you log your CGImageRef?

Comment: What does `-refFromImage:` do? Is it returning something non-nil?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code for `refFromImage:`.

Comment: Updated! Not sure how to log a CGImageRef...

Comment: I think you can log a `CGImageRef` using `NSLog`, if not use `CFShow`.

Comment: Strange I tried NSLog first it gave me a warning now it works : no CGImageRef is nil.

Comment: @Korion: Do you mean “no, the `CGImageRef` is `nil`”, or “none of the `CGImageRef`s are `nil`”?

Answer (score 3):

One part guess at the solution, one part change that will improve the code even if it isn't the solution…

Your number of images in `CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL` is wrong; you should be passing the number of images you expect to add.

Given a loop, you clearly expect to be adding one *or more*. Given your output, you are, in fact, adding more than one image.

You said you would add exactly 1 image, and then you added more than one.

My guess is that the error message is unclear/overly specific. The error says:

> CGImageDestinationFinalize image destination does not have enough images

But I think what it means is:

> CGImageDestinationFinalize image destination has a different number of images than you promised

In other words, the problem isn't that you provided *fewer* images than expected; it's that you provided *more* than expected, and CGImageDestination draws no distinction between more and fewer.

Change your `CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL` call to provide the correct number of images that you'll be adding. Given the code in your question, this should be `source.count`.

Comment: Okay since this solved it, I'm gonna give you the bounty. Now, when I  try to add a 1024x1024 image it says *"ImageIO: <ERROR>  _CGImagePluginWriteICNS unsupported image size (1024 x 1024) - scaling factor: 1"*

Comment: I have to wait 10 hours to award you the bounty will do that then :)

Comment: @Korion: 1024-pixel @ 1x elements in IconFamily images are deprecated as of Mountain Lion. They should be added as 512-point @ 2x (same pixel size, but tagged as 512 @ 2x rather than 1024 @ 1x).

Comment: Oh ok! Silly question, but how does one tag an image?

Comment: @Korion: You don't. You'd do this by setting the point size of the 1024-px images to 512 by 512; CGImageDestination's IconFamily writer will infer the correct scaling factor/resolution from the ratio of the pixel size over the point size.

Comment: Oh okay! I'll update the code today but this seems to be on the right track now. Thanks for all the help Peter, your answers are very well-written!

Comment: Hmmm, this is the last problem I have, any idea what code to use? I set the point size to 512x512 and the pixel size to 1024x1024, shouldn't that work?

Comment: @Korion: You shouldn't need to set the pixel size. You should only set the point size of the image that bears a 1024×1024 representation. (You might also need to set the size of that rep, as well.)

Comment: Even if I set the size of both the image and the rep, and the NSLog statement confirms that this has been done, the error still persists.

Comment: It looks like the image doesn't get resized at all. When I use a 512x512 image, it just adds this image 10 times to an ICNS file.

Comment: It's not meant to get resized. It was 1024×1024 pixels before and it should remain so; you're simply tagging it as 512×512 points @ 2x rather than 1024×1024 points @ 1x. It adds it 10 times? That shouldn't happen. You should ask a separate question about that.

Comment: Yep as @PeterHosey mentioned to elaborate I just count my array of images that its expecting to receive CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.pathToExportedGif],
                                                                        kUTTypeGIF,
                                                                        images.count,//Count local image array
                                                                        NULL);

Answer (score 1):

Going through `-TIFFRepresentation` and `CGImageSource` is highly roundabout. Use [the `CGImageForProposedRect:context:hints:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/CGImageForProposedRect%3acontext%3ahints%3a) instead.

Comment: Yes, I saw that you mentioned this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548059/turning-an-nsimage-into-a-cgimageref, will adapt my code.

Comment: @Korion: Please edit your question to show your amended code and what results from it.